# Heroku cant find my asset pipeline scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I recently moved a few javascripts to my `../vendor/assets/javascripts` folder as recommended somewhere. It works fine locally but when i deploy it to Heroku it stops working.

It cannot find my javascript file anymore.

The problem is that it somehow change the references to contain a fingerprint
like this

> www.mydomain.com/assets/jquery.validate-2dd178feef2ad4ecda69b07a4d281093.min

but if i remove the fingerprint i can see my file on heroku

> www.mydomain.com/assets/jquery.validate.min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that 1 out of these 3 javascripts moved to the vendor folder was actually working. So i tried renaming the 2 other scripts and re deployed them again.

That fixed it...